# Formatting a cell in a row based on matching a different cell value with a column header

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm bonking my head against how to get Google Sheets to highlight one cell in each row of a grid.  Column C is the Finish Date column where users enter a project completion date.  Row 4 is a row of dates (formatted to only show day number), off into the future.

It's similar to a Gantt chart, with text codes in columns to track components of tasks.  I would love to highlight a single cell in each row where the date in column C matches the date in row 4.

Even fancier would be to extend this to highlight 2 cells in each row based on 2 date columns (C and D).  Here's an image of what I'm aiming for:

[image: demo of highlighted cells in the google sheet]

I've tried a number of scripting approaches with no success, and it all just looked so ugly I figured I'd kick this out to the world at large.

Here's a demo sheet, hopefully:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HgS2qEoEHYt_mwp5M7Mm2dXqgEb_DEGvfvM7Qeblgls

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HgS2qEoEHYt_mwp5M7Mm2dXqgEb_DEGvfvM7Qeblgls

Comment: so you want to color those cells based on C, D and 4th row ?

Comment: Yep, exactly.  So Finish Date makes the cell to the right that under that same date turn yellow.  Ship Date turn a cell red (I'm sure if the first one is working I can sort out the second).  I couldn't get code to narrow down to a single cell instead of highlighting entire columns.  What can I say, I'm new to Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **for yellow:** **`=IF(E$4=$C5,1)`**
- **for red:** **`=IF(E$4=$D5,1)`**

[image: 0]

[**demo spreadsheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13hec9UzJT3ALqVW0l0WLIy95uEIce2-XtGlQxtfodNE/edit#gid=0)

Comment: That's great, many thanks.  I feel chagrined I didn't sort that one out, I was doing it the hard way again, haha.